# Copy a row's content to last row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, row

i'm a neophyte at coding google apps script .

I was wondering if it's possible to write a code that automatically

1. copies a first row's content (where i write email|name|phone number...)
2. everytime, creates a new row at the bottom
3. pastes the content from the first row to the last row created
4. Makes first row's content (I already know how)

Then, I will link the code to a button.
So, the first row should work like a simple form that easily brings new data to the end without scrolling the entire sheet.
To start coding that, I registered a macro that does that

```
function insertlastrow1() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange(' **26:26** ').activate();  //activates last row
  spreadsheet.getRange('5:5').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false); //pastes from row 5
};
```

It simply activates last sheet's row and pastes content from row 5. The Range '26:26' should be replaced by 'last row' once it creates a new row. I think I should create a variable that would be wrote instead of absolute reference '26:26'.

I'm so sorry that it will appear a very stupid question but I started learning really a few time ago.

Comment: It is useful to figure Apps Script solutions out using Macros and reading the code, but it may at sometimes be redundant. I suggest you read [Extending Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets). You will get ideas as to how to create a custom menu (to run the script from the UI) and also about other possibilities, such as using Forms linked to a response sheet. The last option could perhaps be what you are looking for. Use a Google form to submit the data, and it automatically goes to the last row of the response sheet. Have you tried this aproach?

Answer (score 2):

Using the [getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow) method you can get the last row number.

**Example:**

```js
function copyLastRow() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var lastRowA1 = lastRow+":"+lastRow
  var newLastRow = (lastRow+1)+":"+(lastRow+1);
  sheet.getRange(lastRowA1).copyTo(sheet.getRange(newLastRow).activate(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
};
```